# Kotlin enum, Companion and unit testing

Tags: unit-testing, kotlin, enums

I have an `enum` in Kotlin with "util" associated functions as part of a `Companion` object and marked as `@JVMStatic` to be able to access them from java code as static methods.
I would like to be able to have some unit testing for that functions.
Is the approach I took bad for testing and what would be the proper approach for Kotlin and testing?

Comment: No, it isn't bad for testing, why would it be? At least assuming they are [pure functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pure_function); if they aren't, it may be bad independently of testing.

Comment: @AlexeyRomanov: Yes they are pure functions. My concern was if the fact that they are in an enum cause complications